# Submit button value vs. hidden input value

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

Could you please tell me the difference between submitting a **submit button value** and submitting a **hidden input value**?

I ask the question especially in regard of the browser compatibility (IE 9+).

So, my problem is actually the following: I know that a posted hidden input value is always correctly read by the server. But I'm not sure if this is the case too, if the value (which I want to post) is part of the `"value"` attribute of a `<button>` tag.

Thank you very much for your time!

P.S: I prepared an example for clarity. It contains a form for each option in my question. When one of the forms is submitted, the corresponding values are read in PHP. Relevant is the user id value.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitUserId']) && !empty($_POST['submitUserId'])) { // Submitted values.
    $userId = $_POST['submitUserId'];
    $userName = $_POST['userName'];

    echo 'Posted user id: ' . $userId;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Posted user name: ' . $userName;

    // Save the new values in db...
} else { // Initial values fetched from db.
    $userId = 123;
    $userName = 'Valentine';

    echo 'Initial user id: ' . $userId;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'Initial user name: ' . $userName;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test - Submit button value vs. hidden input value</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h4>Option 1: Submit <i>user id</i> as submit button value</h4>

        <form action="" method="post" id="formButtonValue" name="formButtonValue">
            <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" value="<?php echo $userName; ?>" />

            <button type="submit" id="submitUserId" name="submitUserId" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>">
                Submit user details
            </button>
        </form>

        <h4>VS.</h4>

        <h4>Option 2: Submit <i>user id</i> as hidden input value</h4>

        <form action="" method="post" id="formHiddenInputValue" name="formHiddenInputValue">
            <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" value="<?php echo $userName; ?>" />

            <input type="hidden" id="submitUserId" name="submitUserId" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>" />

            <button type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton">
                Submit user details
            </button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the submit  .. trasmit  data to the server  .. all the data in inout field hidden or not ..the only diferrence is that in one case you see the filed  and in the second you don't see .

Comment: Use a hidden input if you want to send data *in addition* to the submit button and other visible inputs.

Comment: @scaisEdge, thank you! My problem is actually the following: I know that posting a hidden input value is always correctly read by the server, but I'm not sure if this is the case too if the value (which I want to post) is part of the `"value"` attribute of a `<button>` tag.

Comment: There can nearly be infinitely many hidden inputs with values, but just one submit value when you send the form. Both will be read by the recipient, and it doesn't care or know if it was a submit-button or a hidden value.

Comment: all  the content of the value  atrruibutes (inside the form)  are  trasmitted also for button typical  assign different value to different submit  button  for obatin the button pressed . and manage the server for different action .

Comment: Thanks, @apokryfos. From your point of view, if I want to post a user id as button value, then it should be correctly read by the server, right?

Comment: A browser will send form data from the form input fields, it won't differentiate what sort of input field that data is from. A text input will be the same as a number input or a textarea input  a hidden input or a button input.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Qirel. It seems that I preserved a false perspective on the problem until now. Based on my experience in earlier programming years, when HTML5 was just a draft, it was not recommended to use buttons to send values to the server. I'm glad to see that your comments contradict my current perspective ;-)

Comment: @apokryfos Cool. Then I can enjoy programming my code without worrying about some side effects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the submitting data process, there's no difference at all.

The server side will never know, or care, about how the input being displayed or processed on the client side.

In fact, in your code, the `value`'s, as the one in hidden input, and the one in the button, are both hidden to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Lee. I reedited my question with two phrases regarding browser compatibility and my actual problem. Could you please tell me, if there is still no difference when I use a IE9+, for example? Do you know some side effects, maybe?

Comment: I cannot put hands on ie currently. But I believe there's won't be any side effect, since this is very basic html implementation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think too. I know that this is a base html implementation, but I have in mind that some years ago there were some side effects when using button values and I don't know if they were resolved. Especially in IE. I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

**There is no difference**

Submit user id as submit button value(**var_dump($_POST)**)

```
array(2) { ["userName"]=> string(9) "Valentine" ["submitUserId"]=> string(3) "123" }
```

Submit user id as hidden input value(**var_dump($_POST)**)

```
array(3) { ["userName"]=> string(9) "Valentine" ["submitUserId"]=> string(3) "123" ["submitButton"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Thanks, @syntaxe. I reedited my question with two phrases regarding browser compatibility and my actual problem. Could you please tell me, if there is still no difference when I use a IE9+, for example? Do you know some side effects, maybe?