# Php print problem after using register form with php

Tags: php

I have a problem with this code:
The form for register works but it dosent print the errors, i get nothing. I did copy from a video the code and i tryed looking at it 2-3 times, but i dont see anything wrong.

Thank you for helping

```
<h1>Register</h1>

<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="nume" >Nume</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nume" id="nume"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="email" >Email</label></td>
            <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="pass" >Password</label></td>
            <td><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Varsta minima</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="varsta_min" value="16" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><lable for="varsta" ></lable>Varsta</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="varsta" id="varsta" ></td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="varsta_min_2" value="16">
        <tr>
            <td>Gen</td>
            <td>
                M <input type="radio" name="gen" value="m">
                F <input type="radio" name="gen" value="f">
                N/A <input type="radio" name="gen" value="na">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="locatie" >Locatie</label></td>
            <td>
                <select id="locatie" name="locatie">
                    <option value="b"> Bucuresti </option>
                    <option value="if"> Ilfov </option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="notificari" >Notificari</label></td>
            <td>
                Email<input type="checkbox" name="notificari[]" value="email">
                Sms<input type="checkbox" name="notificari[]" value="sms">
                Push<input type="checkbox" name="notificari[]" value="push">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" id="register" value="register"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<?php

    /**
     * validati
     * nume min 3 caractere
     * parola min 6 caractere
     * varsta >= varsta minima
     * 
     * mesaj succes! <nume>, te-ai inregistrat cu emailul <email>
     * si vei primi notificari pe canalele 1 2 3 / nu vei primi notificari
     * 
     * erroare:
     * eroare 1
     * eroare 2
     */

    // I
    if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
        $erori =array();
    
            // II
        $nume = $_POST["nume"];
        if (strlen(trim($nume)) < 3) {
            $erori[] = "Numele trebuie sa aiba minim 3 caractere.";
        }
    
            // III
        $parola = $_POST["pass"];
        if (strlen(trim($parola)) < 6) {
            $erori[] = "Parola trebuie sa aiba minim 6 caractere.";
        }
    
            // IV
        $varstaMin = $_POST["varsta_min"];
        $varstaMin2 = $_POST["varsta_min_2"];
    
        $varsta = $_POST["varsta"];
        if ($varsta <= $varstaMin) {
            $erori[] = "Varsta minima este de 16 ani.";
        }
    
        if (!empty($erori)) {
            print '<div style="color: red" >';
            print "Au aparut urmatoarele erori: <br>";
            print "<ul>";
            foreach ($erori as $eroare) {
                print "<li>" . $eroare . "</li>";
            }
            print "</ul>";
            print "</div>";
        } else {
            if (isset($_POST["notificari"])) {
                $canale = $_POST["notificari"]; // array
                $mesaj = "Vei primi notificari pe " . implode("/", $canale);
            } else {
                $mesaj = "Nu vei primi notificari.";
            } 
        }
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        print '<div style="color: green" >';
        print "$nume te-ai inregistrat cu email-ul $email si $mesaj";
        print "</div>";
    }
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

[image]
I dont get the red text or the green text from the code

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["register"])) {` will never be triggered

Comment: You are missing a `name="register"` attribute on your submit button. Its the `name` attribute that is used by the browser to generate data into the $_POST. If no name exists, no name value pair is actually sent to the backend

Comment: yes it was missing name  :( :( :( im so angry i put id in place of name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try adding an action to your form directive:

```
<form action="filename.php" method="post">
```

I don't think a form without an action will submit, likely just trigger a page reload.

You may also wish to set `register` via a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="register" value="1">
```

To ensure that if statement is triggered.

Comment: I would guess that `<input type="submit" id="register" value="register">` is where the `name="register"` attribute should be added

Comment: fyi, you can leave out the `action` method, form will be submitted to the current page then

Comment: ...  or change `if (isset($_POST["register"])) {` to `if (isset($_POST["locatie"])) {`

Comment: Related advice: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784301/submit-button-value-vs-hidden-input-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45784301/2943403)